Xero ID for earning rate changes when creating a new earning rate
I am currently integrating a Xero application into my company's ERP system. We are encountering an issue during pay runs, where employees sometimes work different jobs at different pay rates. To avoid manually changing an employee's rate during each fortnightly pay run, we want to create a new pay item for each different job that an employee might be working on.
However, the problem arises when creating a new earning rate via the API (https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/PayItems), as the ID changes each time. According to the documentation, I am sending the entire existing array in my request, however, the EarningRateID in the response is different from EarningRateID in my request for existing earning rates.
Documentation:

Deleting payroll PayItems works as follows. If you include a PayItem type (example: <DeductionTypes>), you must include each <DeductionType> along with their unique Xero identifier, otherwise, it will be deleted. If you omit the PayItem type from your request, all PayItems of that type will not be modified or deleted.

The problem is that we expect to have around 200-300 earning rates. If we need to update the Xero ID for all the previous earning rates, the response time will increase exponentially.
Any advice or solutions to handle this issue more efficiently would be greatly appreciated.
Below is an example of the values I sent in the API request. The Ordinary Hours Day Shift is the existing earning rate in our database, and the Ordinary Hours Casual Day Shift is the new earning rate I am creating.
Values Sent:
{
  "EarningsRates": [
    {
      "EarningRateID": "f94d6266-f939-4581-8b9c-f38cc5ae5ca3",
      "Name": "Ordinary Hours Day Shift",
      "AccountCode": "301",
      "EarningsType": "ORDINARYTIMEEARNINGS",
      "RateType": "RATEPERUNIT",
      "TypeOfUnits": "Hours",
      "RatePerUnit": "1",
      "AllowanceType": "",
      "AllowanceCategory": "",
      "AccrueLeave": "false",
      "IsExemptFromTax": "false",
      "IsExemptFromSuper": "false",
      "IsReportableAsW1": "false"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ordinary Hours Casual Day Shift",
      "EarningsType": "ORDINARYTIMEEARNINGS",
      "RateType": "RATEPERUNIT",
      "AccountCode": "301",
      "TypeOfUnits": "Hours",
      "RatePerUnit": "2",
      "AllowanceType": "",
      "AllowanceCategory": "",
      "AccrueLeave": "false",
      "IsExemptFromTax": "false",
      "IsExemptFromSuper": "false",
      "IsReportableAsW1": "false"
    }
  ]
}

However, the EarningRateID in the response for the Ordinary Hours Day Shift is different from the EarningRateID I sent in the request.
Response Received:
{
  "Id": "d64dcdc3-8a03-421d-8971-5a6f2540b5db",
  "Status": "OK",
  "ProviderName": "ERP NEXT",
  "DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1717548560841)/",
  "PayItems": {
    "EarningsRates": [
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "9267bc11-3d09-4671-903e-b0afef936482",
        "Name": "Ordinary Hours Day Shift",
        "EarningsType": "ORDINARYTIMEEARNINGS",
        "RateType": "RATEPERUNIT",
        "AccountCode": "301",
        "TypeOfUnits": "Hours",
        "RatePerUnit": 1,
        "IsExemptFromTax": false,
        "IsExemptFromSuper": false,
        "IsReportableAsW1": false,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1717548560763+0000)/",
        "CurrentRecord": true
      },
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "79439068-8a3e-454f-9c49-c825d1ba21ab",
        "Name": "Ordinary Hours Casual Day Shift",
        "EarningsType": "ORDINARYTIMEEARNINGS",
        "RateType": "RATEPERUNIT",
        "AccountCode": "301",
        "TypeOfUnits": "Hours",
        "RatePerUnit": 2,
        "IsExemptFromTax": false,
        "IsExemptFromSuper": false,
        "IsReportableAsW1": false,
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1717548560763+0000)/",
        "CurrentRecord": true
      }
    ]
  }
}

